# use ref didn't work - counterElement.getElementById is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

im trying to get my counter div by ref, but it gives me an error "counterElement.getElementById is not a function"

```
export default function CountersCube() {
    const counterWrapper = useRef(null)
    
    useEffect(() => {
        const [counterElement] = counterWrapper.current.children
        const counter = counterElement.getElementById("counter");
        console.log(counter)
    })



  return (
    <div className="countersCubeContainer">
        <div ref={counterWrapper}>
                <div id="counter" data-target="60000">0</div>
        </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: 2 things: first, you can't count on `counterWrapper.current` to exist; you have to check for its existence and handle that case. Second, for the case where `counterWrapper.current` does exist, remove the `.children` part as you don't need that.

Answer (score 1):

`getElementById` is a property of the `document` object, not of every element.

Use `element.querySelector('#id')` instead.

That said, the element with that id **is** a child of `counterElement` so you won't find it by searching it's descendants.

Just use `counterElement` directly. Better yet, put the ref on the counter element instead of its wrapper.

Comment: strange, because in my other compenent (similar 
case) this method with getElementById works great

Comment: @Vasper — I didn't say **window**